# pdf generator error with rodot-regular.ttf, could i store this pdf

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to create a pdf generator with ionic 3 so i used [this](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted) and imported it using

> npm install pdfmake

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as pdfmake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {  }

  pdf(){
    console.log("pdf", pdfmake)
     var dd = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };
    pdfmake.createPdf(dd);

  }

}
```

After executing this i get this error 
`Error: File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system` dont know how to fix this could some one help me to fix this, and save this to my device storage using cordova file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PdfMake uses fonts as data. It converts a tff file in to js and then converts it back to fonts.

So you are simply missing a file

```
<script src='build/vfs_fonts.js'>
```

You can either add that to index html (bad bad bad)

Or you can import it in your ts file and see if pdfmake picks it up.

```
import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
```

If it doesn't you might have to assign it by configuration.
You can read a little bit more into it here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side

Comment: thank you it worked, but a new window opens and displays the pdf file but it does not last for a long time it closes instantly

Comment: Follow their github api. It says you can open download or print after creating it. If you want you can get the pdf url with getDataUrl and then put that in to a pdf plugin or just use download() function. Are you only calling createPdf?@Yokesh